# embedding python error on initialization

Tags: python, c, python-c-api, python-c-extension, python-embedding

when im running C code to call python functions, there's error on Py_Initialize() The error is ImportError: No module named site. Ive tried to put Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]) but it doesnt work. The cmd call is cInterfacePython Test.py multiply 3 2 (exe is cInterfacePython)

Comment: Sounds like your python installation is a bit messed up. Can you tell us more about that?

Comment: i did not install python myself on the machine... so i dont know the details about that...

Comment: @user1023894: I've deleted my post since it wont answer your question. Can you test if python.exe works in the same environment as your own 'cinterfacepython' ?

Comment: If you have no access to this machine then there's little we can do. If `Py_Initialize()` then I would simply bounce the problem back to whoever manages the machine.

Comment: @Macke: i make it work by just moving my entire project to my python.exe directory. But do you know how to set up the environment variables and paths without moving the entire project? like in c code?

Comment: @user1023894: setenv ... see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to muck about a bit with the PATH env-var as well as PYTHONPATH to make things work better when embedding.

Py_SetProgramName is not important, it's mostly for internal reference etc...

So, I suggest you find where python is installed locally (this is available in the registry on Windows machines) and use `setenv` to set PATH and PYTHONPATH to something appropriate. That would be the python.exe directory for PATH (as in your comment above), as well setting PYTHONPATH to the dir with your own python code and related libraries that you're running from the embedding exe.

Then run Py_Initialize and see if the right thing happens. If you need to modify PYTHONPATH afterward initialization, modify sys.path using PySys_SetPath().

Comment: you're using PySide? so setting the path of application to app_path will set the environment path to the python26 files? or the PyRun_SimpleString cmd imports the correct files? But im crashing at Py_initialize....

Comment: I had to set the PYTHONHOME env-var (to the location of python.exe) instead of PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem (Windows, both with Visual Studio and MinGW/g++), and I solved it by adding to PYTHONPATH the path to site.py.
For some reason, launching python.exe was possible even without it, and sys.path did contain that path (even when PYTHONPATH did not), and I could "import site", but Py_Initialize was not able to do the same thing that python.exe did.