# What can cause this error("ImportError:No module name site") when embedding python in c?

Tags: c, python-embedding

I try to run first example of [this simple tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11805/Embedding-Python-in-C-C-Part-I) in order to learn how to embedding python in c applications, but it describes everything in Windows and I am working in Ubuntu Linux.

In first trying, I get segmentation fault and add two lines before Py_Initialize() to overcome this error:

```
char pySearchPath[] = ".:myhome";
Py_SetPythonHome(pySearchPath);
```

Now, I get this error when it want to Py_Initialize() : "ImportError: No module named site".

I found some solution like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232708/embedding-python-error-on-initialization), but they aren't working for me?
What can I do to fix this? I'm a noob in Python too.

Comment: Sorry if the question is stupid, but did you literally write "myhome"?

Comment: myhome means : /home/xxx. It's not correct?

Comment: If you actually wrote `/home/xxx` in your code and this is the wrong place to point at, you might very well get the error you got. Is your module located in this directory?

Answer (score 1):

1) Why not use a tutorial specifically aimed at Linux? There's [one linked](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3641) in the article you reference.

2) Are you sure that you understand [what Py_SetPythonHome](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#Py_SetPythonHome) actually does? It tells Python where the standard Python libraries are. It seems unlikely that you have those stored in ".:myhome" (as you wrote), or "/home/xxx". If you actually do have the standard Python libraries there, please edit your question and post more about your setup and your actual code.